# algorithm for overlaying point cloud on image

Tags: algorithm, image, point-clouds, blending, lidar

I am trying to make a task for an upcoming project and don't know which algorithms to use to solve this problem.

Given:
Let's say I have a 256x256 point cloud from lidar, I also have a 1280x720 RGB image from the camera.
Lidar points comes asynchronously from the image.
The FOV of the lidar and the camera is very different, also the points from the lidar do not match the pixels in the image.

1. For a better understanding, I'm trying to show this in simple simulated images.
   [camera image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/linRz.jpg)

[points from lidar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmIfD.png)

So if we just mix the image and the points, we will get bad results.

2. After some adjustments and scaling, we can observe some acceptable result.
   (color for distance estimation)
   [mixed image - dots with additions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljhX5.jpg)

But in the end result, I need to fill the area with a solid color and highlight the boundaries of the objects.

3. something like this
   [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuGyM.jpg)

So my question is: What kind of math and algorithms do I need to get to go from step 2 to step 3?

P.S. I try to work in OpenCV with C++.

I think i need some region growing\watershed algorithm but for point clouds not images, for filling problem.
After this algorithm will fill spaces between points and form filled objects, edges can be simply find as last points in fill region.

Comment: This is not really a stackoverflow question as its scope is extremely broad. That said, I can point you in (probably) the correct direction. Your lidar points have native 3D positioning, however, the camera pixels do not. You will need to use photogrammetry (or NeRFs) to obtain a point cloud from (multiple) photos of the scene. There are entire fields of study devoted to the latter. You can use a turn-key solution such as agi-soft or figure out how to use opensource ones (openMVG and openMVS, or colmap, or any other.)

Comment: @ldog At the moment I don't think this is a photogrammetry problem. I don't need a detailed 3D reconstruction. For now, I need to solve a less computational problem, namely, colorize the areas that are given by a sparse point cloud.

Comment: if all you care about is coloring the LIDAR points (or any 3D point cloud) based on data from camera images, you can do this by assuming that there are no occlusions (i.e. there is one and only one well defined point that each pixel "sees" or its ray intersects), then project each 3D point to each image, and average the colors in the projection. This is fairly simple to do, but you will likely need to do photogrammetry anyways to correct for drift or other subtle errors.